# Is there any way to run javascript in iBooks without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, ibooks, mixpanel

We've been testing HTML widgets in iBooks 3 and had some success in connecting online. One of the drawbacks, though, is it requires user interaction to actually expand the widget and run Javascript. Is there a way to run Javascript in the background of the iBook, without requiring user interaction outside of regular paging?

For example, if we wanted to have Mixpanel running in the background, how would we do that? Is there another type of widget that allows this to happen? Or is there something else that runs javascript besides the HTML widget?

edit: To clarify, I'm using iBooks Author to create the full book, which has the functionality to add HTML widgets inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a book authored using iBooks Author, which by the way would be a useful detail to put in your question. I don't know iBooks Author or its widget architecture or to what it extent it exposes the ability to place JS on a page.

However, in "normal" ebooks authored in (X)HTML/JS/CSS, there is no essential difference between JS in the reader and in a web browser.

I'm not sure what you mean by "running in the background"; JS runs when something tells it to, whether that something is it being placed on a page in a SCRIPT element, or put it in an onLoad or some other event handler.

Comment: Thanks for asking for the clarification, I edited the original question. I'm specifically asking about iBooks and how the JS model works within it. There's no document.onload, for example, since it's in iBooks, so is there something that's equivalent?

Comment: Well, there is a `document.onload` in iBooks. It basically means that the document has been, uh, loaded and is ready to futz with. The only difference is that the document is not being loaded over the web, but rather being loaded from within the EPUB file.

Answer (score 0):

Widgets in ibooks do not execute JS until they are activated by the user. So even though the link for the widget may be visible in your book, it's not capable of making connections via ajax or doing anything else until launched. Once launched, the widget has no access to the book content either. If you wanted to run mixpanel in a widget you could, but it wouldn't make sense unless your widget also contained all the content of the book (and a reading system).

Comment: Can you run JS anywhere else besides in a widget in iBooks?

Comment: Yes, ibooks will run JS embedded in the content, but in that context, something like mixpanel would not work, because inbound/outbound connections are prohibited (no ajax). Other than that, you can run jQuery, do DOM manipulation, CSS animation, etc.

Comment: Oh, awesome -- is there documentation for how that works? I've only been able to see it in epubs, but not the native ibooks format (that supports widgets).

Comment: There are no docs that I know of specifically for ibooks, although it's a variant of webkit. Apple has never been open about the particular differences between it and mobile safari, but I would look at docs for mobile safari and see what works and what doesnt.