# Integration of iBook with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ibooks

I know that we can embed HTML5 content in iBook using HTML widget,However I want to know if is there any way by which we can open an ibook in HTML page ?

Using a tool or with the help of Jquery or Javascript will do.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: maybe this would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326895/is-there-any-way-to-run-javascript-in-ibooks-without-user-interaction

Comment: and this : https://support.apple.com/kb/ht5068

Comment: Sora,Thank you for the reply,though the link you suggested is not much useful.

Comment: Sora,about second link,its about embedding html5 content in ibook using widget so not what i expect...still thnx...

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by "open an ibook in HTML page". Do you mean you want to view the book in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can open iBooks by using the code:

```
<a href="itms-books:" >Open Book</a>
```

let me know if u help this

Comment: could you please share any example link to give support to your answer ?